# Short os-stats collector failed java.lang.NullPointerException with Cassandra 2.2.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have deployed Datastax Cassandra 2.2.4 windows edition in Windows 7. While I'm attempting to execute COPY command from CSQL Shell, it not responding.

Subsequently when I looked at the log file opcenter-agent.log the following log information is being recorded.Any suggestions to fix the issue?

`ERROR [os-metrics-1] 2016-02-10 15:51:12,015 Long os-stats collector failed
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:798)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:764)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$parse_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:76)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf$wrapped_parser__10730.invoke(win32_util.clj:34)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_results.invoke(proc.clj:105)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_output.doInvoke(proc.clj:119)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:442)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf.doInvoke(win32_util.clj:35)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:146)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at opsagent.proc$safe_from_IOException.doInvoke(proc.clj:338)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:573)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$monitor_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:82)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$collectors$fn__11030.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:276)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_pool$fn__16637.invoke(collection.clj:34)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ERROR [os-metrics-3] 2016-02-10 15:51:27,292 Long os-stats collector failed
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:798)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:764)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$parse_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:76)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf$wrapped_parser__10730.invoke(win32_util.clj:34)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_results.invoke(proc.clj:105)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_output.doInvoke(proc.clj:119)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:442)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf.doInvoke(win32_util.clj:35)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:146)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at opsagent.proc$safe_from_IOException.doInvoke(proc.clj:338)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:573)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$monitor_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:82)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$collectors$fn__11030.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:276)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_pool$fn__16637.invoke(collection.clj:34)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ERROR [os-metrics-5] 2016-02-10 15:51:42,631 Long os-stats collector failed
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:798)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:764)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$parse_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:76)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf$wrapped_parser__10730.invoke(win32_util.clj:34)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_results.invoke(proc.clj:105)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_output.doInvoke(proc.clj:119)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:442)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf.doInvoke(win32_util.clj:35)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:146)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at opsagent.proc$safe_from_IOException.doInvoke(proc.clj:338)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:573)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$monitor_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:82)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$collectors$fn__11030.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:276)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_pool$fn__16637.invoke(collection.clj:34)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ERROR [os-metrics-10] 2016-02-10 15:51:57,893 Long os-stats collector failed
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:798)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:764)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$parse_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:76)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf$wrapped_parser__10730.invoke(win32_util.clj:34)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_results.invoke(proc.clj:105)
    at opsagent.proc$parse_output.doInvoke(proc.clj:119)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:442)
    at opsagent.util.win32_util$typeperf.doInvoke(win32_util.clj:35)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:146)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at opsagent.proc$safe_from_IOException.doInvoke(proc.clj:338)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:573)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$monitor_queue_size.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:82)
    at opsagent.os.win32_metrics$collectors$fn__11030.invoke(win32_metrics.clj:276)
    at opsagent.os.collection$start_pool$fn__16637.invoke(collection.clj:34)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ERROR [os-metrics-13] 2016-02-10 15:52:02,353 Short os-stats collector failed
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 ERROR [os-metrics-5] 2016-02-10 15:52:02,548 wmic.exe failed on execute; returning default value - Process failed: wmic LogicalDisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceId,Size,FreeSpace /Format:csv
  Exit val: 44210
  Output:
Invalid XSL format (or) file name.`

Comment: Add the command line you ran in cqlsh so we can all see what you ran to generate the error.

Comment: COPY datalog FROM 'InternetTraffic.csv' WITH HEADER = true ;